# Can we avoid cookie creation for cloud pages?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

We found out that MC creates 2 cookies by default when you access any cloud page, it creates two cookies with ADRUM prefix name:

[image: cookies]

Is there a way to avoid the creation of these cookies? Do you know the purpose of these two?
I coudln't find any information regarding cookies and cloud pages in https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_cp_cloudpages.htm&type=5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This discussion came up somewhere else in the community a while ago, and someone reached out to Support. This is the answer they got:

> These cookies [“ADRUM_BTa & ADRUM_BT1”] track errors that users may receive and provide our technical teams with insight to make sure that we can improve your user experience.These do not store or process PII [Personally identifiable information] but are more used for debugging errors and improving the system reliability.

As for removing those cookies - I don't think it is possible, but Support will be the ones who can give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 4):

The ADRUM* cookies are set by AppDynamics, which is used for performance monitoring. They are anonymous and hence can't be tied to any contact in Marketing Cloud, nor are they used to identify visitor across other sites, and can't be used maliciously to obtain sensitive data.

You can read more about this monitoring here:
https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO40/Set+Up+Your+Application+for+Web+EUEM

Answer (score 1):

just opened a SalesForce ticket for that.
Result ? it confirms we -as CloudPage owner/dev- cannot avoid cookie post : they are mandatory.

Here is their complete answer.

"I'd like to inform you that the cookies “ADRUM_BTa & ADRUM_BT1” are required and currently can't be removed or disabled due to the following reasons:
These cookies are used for performance monitoring. They are anonymous and not tied to any contact in Marketing cloud and cannot be used to identify visitors.
This is also essential to support to track errors that users may receive and provide us technical information in order to troubleshoot cloud-page issue and help improve user experiences. As mentioned by you these do not store or process PII [Personally identifiable information] but are more used for debugging errors and improving the system reliability.
Due to the reasons above this cannot be removed."